# Receiving mails on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

i'm new to iOS iphone programming;

I'm interested in receiving files in attachment from the e-mails and save those files, that my application could use them. I do not know how to retrieve those emails;

I would be grateful for any ideas on approaches to this problem.

Comment: you can not send mail through simulator you must need to use device for sending mail

Comment: You will need a device to do a full application testing.  See Hemang answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Sending / Receiving emails is depends on `Message UI` framework and Apple doc says, **YOU JUST CAN'T!** which isn't supported in Simulator.

See the doc here, [Testing and Debugging in iOS Simulator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html)